# Map leaflet markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I try to develop an application to show services on a leaflet map:

Is it possible to have different markers according to the "properties" geojson attribute ?

`{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 6.1200622,46.2106091 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "nom":"Cfffff Genève",
    "rue":"Route des F",
    "num":"11",
    "npa":1203,
    "localite":"Genève",
    "canton":"GE",
    "tel":"033 345 17 57",
    "url":"www.formation-cemea.ch",
    "domaine":"société   "
    }},`

here is my script for the map:[image]
  i want that when you click on a button on the top it  show only the markers corresponding to the properties (with another color) ?
THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH for any help ;)

```html
  <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" id="allbus" class="btn btn-success">All</button>
          <button type="button" id="others" class="btn btn-primary">Sexualité</button>
          <button type="button" id="cafes" class="btn btn-danger">Mal-être</button>
          <button type="button" id="cafes" class="btn btn-secondary">Santé</button>
          <button type="button" id="cafes" class="btn btn-info">Drogues</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Société</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Internet</button>
      </div>


  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

  var map = L.map('map');
  var terrainTiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.wmflabs.org/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
  });

  terrainTiles.addTo(map);
  map.setView([46.5160000, 6.6328200], 10);

  L.control.locate(location).addTo(map);

  L.easyButton( '<strong>BE</strong>', function(){
    //zoomTo.setView([55, -2], 4);
    map.setView([46.95, 6.85], 12);
  }).addTo(map);

  L.easyButton( '<strong>FR</strong>', function(){
    //zoomTo.setView([55, -2], 4);
    map.setView([46.95, 6.85], 12);
  }).addTo(map);
  L.easyButton( '<strong>GE</strong>', function(){
    //zoomTo.setView([55, -2], 4);
    map.setView([46.95, 6.85], 12);
  }).addTo(map)

  L.easyButton( '<strong>JU</strong>', function(){
    //zoomTo.setView([55, -2], 4);
    map.setView([46.95, 6.85], 12);
  }).addTo(map);
  L.easyButton( '<strong>NE</strong>', function(){
    //zoomTo.setView([55, -2], 4);
    map.setView([46.95, 6.85], 12);
  }).addTo(map);

  L.easyButton( '<strong>VS</strong>',  function(){
    //zoomTo.setView([55, -2], 4);
    map.setView([46.95, 6.85], 12); 
  }).addTo(map);

  L.easyButton( '<strong>VD</strong>', function(){
    //zoomTo.setView([55, -2], 4);
    map.setView([46.95, 6.85], 12);
  }).addTo(map);


  function addDataToMap(data, map) {
      var dataLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
          onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
              var popupText = "<b>" + feature.properties.nom
                  + "<br>" 
                  + "<small>"  + feature.properties.localite 
                  + "<br>Rue: " + feature.properties.rue + + feature.properties.num
                  + "<br>Téléphone: " + feature.properties.tel
                  + "<br><a href= '" + feature.properties.url + "'>Internet</a>";
              layer.bindPopup(popupText); }
          });

      dataLayer.addTo(map);
  }

  $.getJSON("data.geojson", function(data) { addDataToMap(data, map); });



  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the layer instance in your `onEachFeature` method, check if it's a marker and set it's icon:

```
new L.GeoJSON(null ,{
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
            layer.setIcon(new L.Icon(...));
        }
    }
})
```

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#icon

Example: http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/

Answer (score 0):

You can use circle markers `L.circleMarker` to differentiate your points based on `feature.properties.[VALUE]`. And you can add a filter also. For instance, based on `TotalImpct` property:

```
munCustomLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
        onEachFeature: {SOME FUNCTION},

        filter: function (feature, layer) {
             return feature.properties.TotalImpct > 10000;
        },
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) { //Style the layer based on TotalImpact
            if (feature.properties.TotalImpct < 50000){
                return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
                    radius: 5,
                    color: "#e0e0e0",
                    opacity: 0.95,
                    weight: 1.2,
                    dashArray: "2,3",
                    fillOpacity: 0.01,
                });    
            } 
(...)
```

You can see an example using circle markers [here](https://cccruzr.github.io/maps/docs/masacres.html). (Remember to check the source code).